# Mac laptop (Version 10.9.4) crashes after some time when I connect my Huwawei Dongle

Tags: mac

My Mac laptop (Version 10.9.4) has some crashing issue with my STC Huwawei Dongle. When I connected to internet using my dongle the Mac crashes and automatically restart. My dongle model number is E173u-2. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any error messages when the crash occurs? If so, please edit your qestion and add them.

Comment: No There were no error messages. It crashes after some time and restarted and appears the white screen and says "Your computer is restarted because of a problem!!!" only...